# div:hover only working with mouse down in firefox and safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

the goal is to make my linkIcon background change background images when I hover my mouse over it. It works completely fine in chrome, but in firefox and safari nothing changes when I hover my mouse over the linkIcon unless I have my mouse button down when my mouse moves on top of the div.  I can't figure out what the difference is. 
Html:

```
<div id="tab" >
<div id="swingDownButtonContainer">
    <a href="javascript:slideLinks();" style="display:block; position:relative;">
    <div id="linkIcon">
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#tab {
z-index:-1;
background-color:#f0996f;
position:absolute;
left:-10px;
height:20%;
width:50px;
border-radius:10px;
top:40%;
}
#swingDownButtonContainer {
text-align:center;
}
#linkIcon {
z-index:2;
background-image:url('media/circles_noHover.png');
background-size:40px 57px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:40px;
height:60px;
position:absolute;
left:10px;
}
#linkIcon:hover {
    background-image:url('media/circles_Hover.png');
}
```

Comment: your code works fine in firefox and safari for me. What versions are you using?

Comment: I'm using 26.0 on my pc and on my mac for firefox, and 6.0.5 for safari on my mac. I had an outdated version for firefox on my pc before I updated recently and it didn't work on that either. I forget which version I had, however.

Comment: do you have a link to the page you can post? Or can you recreate this in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably finding your link has no height as it's contents are absolutely positioned. Can you change it to:

```
<div id="tab" >
<div id="swingDownButtonContainer">
<a id="linkIcon" href="javascript:slideLinks();">
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS edit:

```
#swingDownButtonContainer {
text-align:center;
position: relative;
}
```

Alternatively give the link a height of 60px